# IOS 7 Black bars at the top and bottom (running 3.5 only)

Tags: ios, xcode

I seem to have some across and interesting issue that I can not resolve. I have a app written in XCode 5 running ios 7.1.

The app was working perfectly until I moved the folder location of the project. When I ran up the app on my phone the app worked perfectly but now I no longer get a app icon, launch image and the whole thing seems to only run in 3.5" mode as well, even on my phone (5S). I get black bars at the top and bottom.

I have renamed the folder that the project now sits under back to the original name but this issue has not gone away.

I was wondering if anybody else has ever come across this??

Cheers

Geraint

Comment: you are missing your launch image

Comment: no all images are included, I literally just moved the folder the the project was under to a different workspace and now the app only seems to run in 3.5" mode even on a 4" device. All the other images still work fine.

Comment: set use assest catalogs fro launch image.

Comment: did you get solution?

Comment: not yet, I have tried the link below but the black bars are still there and it is only appearing in 3.5 format. May just have to revert back in Git, but I will post if I find away cheers.

Comment: how did you alloc UIWindow object in appDelegate?

Answer (score 6):

It seems your pbxproject got a bit messed up (maybe you had absolute paths used ? )

Select your target in Xcode.

Under general, App Icons , re-assign the launch images.

The clean and rebuild your project.

Check this link out as well :
[Black bars showing when running app on iOS 7 (4 inch retina display)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913105/black-bars-showing-when-running-app-on-ios-7-4-inch-retina-display)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue manually, seems like it is a bug with Xcode for now and I will file a radar report.

To resolve the issue, follow the below steps:

Navigate to project settings
Under "App Icons and Launch Images" click on "Use Asset Catalog"
Select "Migrate" on the popup that appears.
This should fix the issue.