# iOS Application Doesn't Fill iPhone Screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xcode5, xamarin

I am writing an iPhone app using *Xamarin*.  My `UIViewController` does not fill the entire screen, there is a gap above and below.  Here is a screen shot from the simulator.  I have changed the colour scheme to make the gaps more obvious

[image]

The screen design was done in Xcode below is a screen shot of the settings for the `UIViewController` in Xcode.

[image: XCode settings]

What am I doing wrong, why is the View too small?

Comment: You are missing the correct launch screens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Black bars showing when running app on iOS 7 (4 inch retina display)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913105/black-bars-showing-when-running-app-on-ios-7-4-inch-retina-display)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Put a 4" launch screen image into your asset catalog or `info.plist`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was expecting it to be something simple.

Comment: Can you explain why this is the fix? I am trying to fix this same problem and couldn't figure out where to put my files.

Comment: When apple first released the iPhone 5 (4" screen), they needed a way for developers to "tell" the device that their app supported the new 4" screen. Apple's solution was to detect if they had a 4" launch image as this is something that apps already on the store wouldn't have. To avoid breaking every single existing app, if there is no 4" launch image, the app will launch in a letterbox mode where the height of the UIWindow remained at 480pts instead of 586pts. Adding the 4" launch image tells the device that this app is ready for a 4" screen and that it doesn't have to letterbox it.

Comment: I'm having this problem and have a Retina 4 launch image set but it's not working. Is there a specific size the image needs to be.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this issue when running my app on an iPhone 7. There was a black bar along the bottom.

I tried following the other answers but the `iOS Launch Image` is marked as `Depricated` in `Xcode 12.5.1`

What solved it for was to add the `UILaunchScreen` key and empty `<dict/>` to my `Info.plist` file like this:

```
...
<plist·version="1.0"> 
<dict> 
...
    <key>UILaunchScreen</key>
    <dict/>
...
</dict> 
</plist>
```

If your using xcode to generate your project files this is probably not an issue, but my `.xcodeproj` and `Info.plist` are generated by the `xcodegen` tool which did not add this key-value to my plist.

If your project does not have a `info.plist` file, you need to go to targets->info and click on + icon to add the key and value (dictionary)

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. xcodegen 2.25.0 and xcode 13.2.1 (13C100)

Comment: This worked for me, XCode 15.1, iOS 17.0