# iOS 7 app doesn't fill the whole screen in Xcode 6 simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

iOS 7 app doesn't fill the whole screen in Xcode 6 simulator. But when i set the app to target iOS 8, it works fine. Here are two screen captures:

> This is for iOS 7

[image]

> This is for iOS 8

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: You're missing a 4" launch image.

See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929565/ios-application-doesnt-fill-iphone-screen/25929645#25929645

Comment: It looks like your app is running in the 3.5" mode on the 4" screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these solutions:

1. Try to create launch images(640*960 @2x.png & 640*1136 -568h@2x.png) and set them into project properties for "Launche images source".

or

2. Create .xib file with active autolayout and set this file as "launch screen file".