# Window doesn't fill all screen

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm a beginner with Xamarin and this is my first App. I'm doing just the first steps: create a view. My problem is that it doesn't fill all the screen. I deleted the view and then, I created a Window with the same problem.

This is the XIB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="6211" systemVersion="14A298i" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="6204"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="LoginView">
            <connections>

              <outlet property="window" destination="7" id="176-fQ-JAJ"/>
            </connections>
        </placeholder>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <window opaque="NO" clearsContextBeforeDrawing="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="7">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
            <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
            <simulatedStatusBarMetrics key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
            <simulatedScreenMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics" type="retina4"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-0.2000008" y="20.2"/>
            <subviews>
                <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="Label" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" minimumFontSize="10" id="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" fixedFrame="YES">
                    <rect key="frame" x="139" y="33" width="42" height="21"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
            </subviews>
        </window>
    </objects>
    <resources>
        <image name="Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/ic_launcher_120x120.png" width="120" height="120"/>
        <image name="Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/ic_launcher_152x152.png" width="152" height="152"/>
        <image name="Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/ic_launcher_180x180.png" width="180" height="180"/>
        <image name="Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/ic_launcher_29x29.png" width="29" height="29"/>
        <image name="Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/ic_launcher_40x40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
        <image name="Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/ic_launcher_58x58.png" width="58" height="58"/>
        <image name="Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/ic_launcher_76x76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
        <image name="Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/ic_launcher_80x80.png" width="80" height="80"/>
        <image name="Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/ic_launcher_87x87.png" width="87" height="87"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Edit.

```
 public partial class LoginView : BaseView<LoginViewModel>
    {
        public LoginView() : base("LoginView", null)
        {
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

    }
```

BaseView:

```
 public abstract class BaseView<TViewModel> : MvxViewController, IView<TViewModel> where TViewModel : IViewModel
    {
        private IConfigurationService configurationService;
        private IGlobalizationService globalizationService;

        public BaseView(string nibName, NSBundle bundle) : base(nibName, bundle)
        { }

        public IConfigurationService ConfigurationService
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.configurationService == null)
                {
                    this.configurationService = Mvx.Resolve<IConfigurationService>();
                }

                return this.configurationService;
            }
        }
        public IGlobalizationService GlobalizationService
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.globalizationService == null)
                {
                    this.globalizationService = Mvx.Resolve<IGlobalizationService>();
                }

                return this.globalizationService;
            }
        }
        public new TViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return (TViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
            set { base.ViewModel = value; }
        }
```

[image: This is how the view is shwoing]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Application Doesn't Fill iPhone Screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929565/ios-application-doesnt-fill-iphone-screen)

Comment: I'm using MVVM Cross, so I don't use UIViewController  or a launch screen. I don't use Xcode as well... I develop with Visual Studio. I did my own LaunchScreen without calling it through info.plist

Comment: Hi Daniel, how are you building up your view or ViewController? MvvmCross is just a very thin wrapper around a native iOS ViewController.. Can you show the code for the actual view controller or how you are creating the view? We need a little more info to go on.

Comment: @Stephanvs I add a capture as well. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't have any problem with the buttom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe solution is adding this code in ViewDidLoad function

```
        NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;
```

Comment: I'm glad you solved it, but your description of "window doesn't fill screen" was horribly inaccurate