# Fill iPhone X Screen with Xamarin.Forms App

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, iphone-x

I have an iPhone app I created using Xamarin.Forms.  Recently, I tried looking at my app on the iPhone X simulator and found that there is blank space at the top and bottom of the phone as shown in this picture:

[image: iPhone X with black space]

I saw in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929565/ios-application-doesnt-fill-iphone-screen) that when the iPhone 5 came out, there was a similar issue that was fixed by adding a launch screen image of a different size.

Does anyone know the fix for iPhone X? Is it a launch screen issue or something else?  Are there any other things that should be done to a Xamarin.Forms app to make it compatible with iPhone X?

Comment: see https://blog.xamarin.com/updating-xamarin-ios-apps-for-the-iphone-x/

Comment: What about for Xamarin.Forms? I'm not using a storyboard

Comment: you don't have a launch screen in your iOS project?

Comment: You need to add a launch storyboard to your project or add launch images of the right size to let iOS know you app works on the iPhone x

Comment: Are you referring to the launch images in my asset catalog? How do I add new ones for iPhone X?

Comment: In iOS 8 (and later), the developer can create a special Unified Storyboard to provide the Launch Screen instead of using one or more static launch images.  RE:https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/#Managing_Launch_Screens_with_Storyboards

Comment: Thank you, I missed that change in iOS 8

Comment: @ColeXia What does the launch screen have to do with other pages in the app?

Comment: @KevinLe-Khnle I don't get you ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem on an old Xamarin Forms project.

You probably don't have the launch image for the iPhone X (that was my case). I just replaced my launch images asset with a storyboard for launch screen and it was good.

Hope it helps !

Comment: How do you do this with Visual Studios on Windows (When connected to a Mac)?