# Screen deformed iOS7 and iOS8

Tags: ios7, ios8, screen

I'm trying to compilate the app in iOS 7 and iOS 8

This is the result :

iOS 7 : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/710911Capturedcran20141011181204.png
iOS 8 : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/304898Capturedcran20141011181211.png

Someone know why ? I never had a problem like that.

Comment: Do you have any container view inside your controller?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913105/black-bars-showing-when-running-app-on-ios-7-4-inch-retina-display