# Layout issue with Swift and Xcode 6.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Hi i'm just starting to use the new xcode.

I simply start with the single view application, i set it for iphone only, and i set the storyboard to the 4inches iphone.

if i run the iphone 7.1 simulator the screen gets cut

[image: 7.1]

if i run the iphone 8 simulator all goes well.

[image: 8]

why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Black bars showing when running app on iOS 7 (4 inch retina display)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913105/black-bars-showing-when-running-app-on-ios-7-4-inch-retina-display)

Comment: The "duplicate" solution is a bit outdated - the launch image setup in XCode 6 is different now. Need to manually create a new Launch Image group in the image assets, then drag in launch images at the correct size. Kind of a silly bug, but at least it sort of forces you to make sure you add the required images...

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the issue you're having is in [another SO answer about black bars showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913105/black-bars-showing-when-running-app-on-ios-7-4-inch-retina-display), but the *reason* is different.

iOS 8 added the ability to have a `LaunchScreen.xib` document instead of a series of images, but XIB launch screens aren't supported by earlier iOS releases. You'll need to add launch images as described in the linked answer.