# Xcode 6.1 black strips- iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7

I've problem with back strips on the top and bottom of iPhone 5/5s simulator with iOS 7.1.
Project is set on iOS 7.1 > deployment target. Currently I use Xcode 6.1 (the latest one), elements on storyboard are arranged with auto layout.

Everything works well on all devices with iOS8 and iOS 7 iPhone 4/4s as well.

Comment: Please check an answer from this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913105/black-bars-showing-when-running-app-on-ios-7-4-inch-retina-display

Answer (score 2):

Check your launch images and xcassets catalogue images. Once images of correct size will be placed there it will work just fine. Right now you have only placed images for only 3.5 inch screens. and removing even the default 4inch screen images.
Or simply delete the existing images xcassests catalogue and create new one.
It worked for me