# iOS 8 - View is not resizing full screen

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8, mainwindow

I have old code using the MainWindow.xib, below iOS 7 everything works fine but in iOS 8 its leaving some bottom area.

Attaching image - [image]

Please suggest anyone, how can i fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem while ago. Turned out I had deleted the launch screen.

To make it right, add launch screen back by going in general setting of your project and adding your launch xib there.

[image]

I hope this fix your problem.

Comment: Launch screen is there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913105/black-bars-showing-when-running-app-on-ios-7-4-inch-retina-display

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding new Launchimages. Removed my old ones and created a "New Launch Image". Also take a look at your autoresizing in the xib file under the "Size Inspector".