# Phonegap + iphone 6 screen size issue

Tags: ios, iphone, angularjs, cordova

I'm using phonegap / cordova with AngularJS to create a mobile app.

I'm testing the application in chrome debugger and simular all iPhones 4-6 plus, the layout stretch itself automatically and everything looks good.

when i'm running the application on iPhone 6 i get 2 black strips at the bottom and at the top of the app and the application size is small and not covering the whole screen.

Did it happen to anyone? how did you solve it?

Attached example image.

[image]

Comment: Do you used Phonegap Build to pack app. Issue involve splash screen incorrect size or missing splash screen image for device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

[Black bars showing when running app on iOS 7 (4 inch retina display)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913105/black-bars-showing-when-running-app-on-ios-7-4-inch-retina-display)

This helped when I had this issue on iPhone 5, seems to solve iPhone 6 as well.

Comment: @trueincecol the link is not relevant for iOs 8 / iphone 6 / 6+

Comment: Did you create both variations of the image? regular and retina (@2x)?
Did you put those splash screens in the right place?