# iOS - Converting an iPad app to a universal app - resolution issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, screen-resolution, ios-universal-app

I have an `iPad app`, which now needs to be converted into a `universal` one. I've set the target to `Universal` and now it can be deployed to an `iPhone` as well, however, I have a major issue: even though I've created my main view controller separately for the two device types, when I launch the app on an `iPhone 5`, the screen seems to have a resolution of `320x480`, leaving black space on top and under the view. This doesn't seem to be an issue with the main window, because I changed the `window's background` to `red`, and the space filling up the height to `568px` is still black, which means, that the window is also only `320x480`.

Any help / idea would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried it on simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the answer to this question:

Q: [Black bars showing when running app on iOS 7 (4 inch retina display)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913105/black-bars-showing-when-running-app-on-ios-7-4-inch-retina-display)

A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18913189/4666621

You're probably missing the image **Default-568h@2x.png**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, indeed, it was a beginner mistake, but I didn't add the launch image for the 4" model.