# Choosing Launch Screen File in Xcode makes my app launch slow on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have an app I'm about to launch to the Appstore, however, when I created an archive of my app in Xcode (developed in PhoneGap), it automatically compiled asset catalogs for icons and splash screens, and set the launch screen image to `MainViewController` in the settings. Because of that, my app takes a few seconds to launch after I tap the app icon on my phone and it doesn't show the splash screen (which worked perfectly when Launch Screen File was empty). Now, when I remove the Launch Screen File, my app launches quickly and normally, shows the splash screen, but now my app appears completely zoomed in.

How can I fix this? It's really annoying.

**EDIT:** Someone suggested an edit saying this has nothing to with Cordova. But it might. This app was built using Cordova CLI. When it was freshly built, no launch screen file was selected, but the app did't zoom in as it does now, when no launch screen file is selected. How can Cordova make an app appear normal without a selected launch screen file, but does it not work after archiving?

Comment: by "zoomed in", do you mean it is appearing letterboxed with black bars above and below your view?

Comment: No, everything is literally zoomed in and appears bigger. There was a question on SO about it, and the accepted answer was `select a Launch Screen File`. So usually that should fix the zooming, but for me it makes the app launch very slowly and it makes the app not show any splash screen at all.

Comment: have you tried adding static launch images as shown in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18913189/2976878? (oops, corrected the link)

Comment: @originaluser2 That did the trick, thanks!