# App screen size off

Tags: ios, swift

I just bought my developers license from Apple so I could test my app out on my phyiscal phone so I could get a feel for how the app moves and how the UX feels but when I run it, the screen looks like this.

[image]

What is up with the black top and bottom? It looks fine in the storyboard, I have size classes off and auto layout on and all the constraints are perfectly fine so why would it be doing this? I have an iPhone 6.

Comment: *"I just bought my developers license from Apple so I could test my app out on my phyiscal phone"* - you do realize that a paid account is not necessary for that!?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913105/black-bars-showing-when-running-app-on-ios-7-4-inch-retina-display & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845459/black-space-in-ios-app-in-4inch-screen?lq=1

Comment: This happens across all your views?

Comment: Does my answer helped you Griffin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your app settings and set like this:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: you should also probably check that you have a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file in your bundle (set the background color to transparent if you don't want an explicit launch screen)..

Comment: what has LaunchScreen to do with this? How is this a possible fix for the user?

Comment: hi @TastyCat I'm not saying it's not the answer...but why?