# How to set top margin of table view in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am  new to iOS development, and my code is running fine in iOS6, but in iOS7 it has some UI issues.

Please see following image. I wanted to add margin to table view, but as stated it was perfect in iOS 6. Question may seem very basic, but I am trying to find any property using which I can add margin.

Secondly, if I need to do it programmatically, please suggest where I should write the code.

I tried to search on google, but may be I am not able to search with correct terms. I am C++ developer and new to Objective C and Mac.

[image]

Comment: What margin? Could you show what you had in iOS6 that you want to replicate?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909991/status-bar-is-overlapping-with-the-view-in-ios7

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775874/ios-7-status-bar-overlaps-the-view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by setting your tableViews contentInset or contentOffset depending on your needs.

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)];
```

Answer (score 0):

On your table view controller, set the `edgesForExtendedLayout` property to `UIRectEdgeTop`.

You can use this property to extend views beneath top bars, (status and navigation bars) and bottom bars (toolbars and tab bars).

The value is a bit mask with possible values of:

```
UIRectEdgeNone,
UIRectEdgeTop,
UIRectEdgeLeft,
UIRectEdgeRight,
UIRectEdgeBottom,
UIRectEdgeAll
```