# UINavigation bar not expanding under the status bar unless it has a UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I am working with iOS7 trying to expand the edges of my `UINavigationBar` so that it goes under the `UIStatusBar`.

I know how to achieve that with an attached `UINavigationController` into my `UIViewController` and a `64pp image background`  that I set with `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BlackBackground"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

As shown in the picture, the `UINavigationBar` is not being attached under the `UIStatusBar` (and thats why you cant see time it is not a gap I am using `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` ).

Is there a way to make it expand under the `UIStatusBar` without a `UINavigationController`?(I am trying to avoid hacky solutions)

The problem one

[image]

This is how it works in another view but with a `UINavigationController` attached
[image]

Comment: So you use UINavigationBar without UINavigationController on first screen, am i right?

Comment: I use `UINavigationBar` in a few places without using `UINavigationControllers` and that wasnt a problem until iOS 7 that it nows give 2 different styles to my views

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to present a view controller on iOS7 without the status bar overlapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912290/how-to-present-a-view-controller-on-ios7-without-the-status-bar-overlapping)