# Status bar is over views in iOS7 without Storyboard

Tags: ios, ios7

I created my first app with iOS7 SDK, a "empty application" without Storyboard.
The status bar is always over all other views.
So I add this code :

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

But it changes nothing. My full code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 200, 300)];
    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:v];
}
```

Comment: would you like to hide (or get rid of) the status bar or just have your views positioned correctly below the status bar?

Comment: The views below the status bar, as on iOS6.

Comment: is your question answered by [this potentially duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912290/how-to-present-a-view-controller-on-ios7-without-the-status-bar-overlapping)???

Comment: So, I must use Storyboard ?

Comment: Not at all. Only one answer in that related/duplicate question applies only to storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

edgesForExtendedLayout applies only in presence of a UI container view controller (such as UINavigationController). To avoid that overlapping, you should use -topLayoutGuide (it also exist a bottom layoutGuide). I've made a [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/DrAma999/6554189) that use a container view as a subview of the vc main view with this layout set.

```
//This should be added before the layout of the view
- (void) adaptToTopLayoutGuide {
    //Check if we can get the top layoutguide
    if (![self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)]) {
        return;
    }
    //tankView is a contaner view
    NSArray * array = [self.tankView referencingConstraintsInSuperviews]; //<--For this method get the Autolayout Demistified Book Sample made by Erica Sadun
    [self.view removeConstraints:array];
    NSArray * constraintsVertical = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[topLayoutGuide]-0-[tankView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"tankView": self.tankView, @"topLayoutGuide":self.topLayoutGuide}];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraintsVertical];
    NSArray * constraintsHorizontal = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[tankView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"tankView": self.tankView}];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraintsHorizontal];

}
```

This snippet make a control to see is we have a topLayoutGuide, later it removes the constraints on the tankView (that is a container view added and connected in a xib) related to the superview and it adds new constraints based on the topLayoutGuide.