# Navigation bar and Status bar issue in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, navigationbar, ios7-statusbar

I have created an application using `XIB` without `Status Bar` before for `iOS7`, now i need to add `Status bar` on my app and `Status bar background color` should same as `Navigation bar` background color. So i have tried like (In my `info.plist`) :

```
1) Set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO
2) Set Status bar style to UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
```

here is my code for `App Delegate`:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(51/255.0) green:(51/255.0) blue:(51/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(51/255.0) green:(51/255.0) blue:(51/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
```

So i am getting the output like the below image :

[image]

also i am getting misplacement of UIButtons that i have given below in my screen (It's hiding 20 pixels).

Can you please help me that how can i fix this issue? I need my output like the below image :

[image]

Any help will be very appreciated, Thanks.

Third screen :

[image]

Comment: You are clipping to bound and the bound has an origin.y of 20px. That seems to be the problem?

Comment: @DanqingThanks, can you please tell me what changes i need to do?

Comment: Why are giving window y co-ordinate as 20?

Comment: well, first remove these two lines I guess?

Comment: Thanks @NagaMalleshMaddali, now i have removed window y co-ordinate (20 pixels)..so i am getting the output like my attached first image, i have updated my question pls check

Comment: how to separate Status Bar and Navigation Bar? pls help me..

Comment: @DanqingCan you please suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

Add following code in your viewDidLoad method :

```
float systemVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if (systemVersion >= 7.0) 
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Comment: Mallesh MaddaliI have added the same in my viewDidLoad method, but still i am getting the same output as image 1. How to separate Status bar and Navigation bar?

Comment: Try by removing following code from AppDelegate: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

Comment: Thanks @Naga I have removed mentioned lines.. now i am getting output without status bar.

Comment: Check by adding only this line : [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

Comment: After adding this.. i am getting output with Status bar as my attached image 3. pls check..

Comment: @user2786, try to use UIBarPositioningDelegate solution from this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948505/uinavigationbar-status-bar-issue-in-ios7. I think your problem is because of auto layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56517/discussion-between-naga-mallesh-maddali-and-user2786).

Answer (score 1):

Please define this in AppDelegate.h (or) constants.h

```
  #define isIOS7  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue] >=7.0)?YES:NO
```

under viewDidLoad Write this lines.

```
  if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
   UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
   addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
    addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.973 green:0.973 blue:0.973 alpha:1];


     //change this to match your navigation bar
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:addStatusBar];
  }
```

OR we can change it manually in the xib.

By moving each element 20px down.

[image: Seethis image]

Answer (score 0):

Surprise at how few people have suggested this. Here is the correct way (no hacking)

First, make your navigationBar have a Y origin of 20.

Then in the .h file, set your ViewController as a UIBarPositioningDelegate:

```
@interface XYZViewController : UIViewController <UIBarPositioningDelegate>
```

And in the .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationBar.delegate = self;
}

- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar { 
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached; 
}
```