# How to make NavigationBar and StatusBar same background in iOS 7?

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, ios7-statusbar

I use Xcode 5 to create a master detail project. The default navigation bar looks like this:

[image]

Now I create a new UIViewContrller file and its xib file:

[image]

I add a NavigationBar to the view, and set background color green, but the status bar area is in navigation bar.How to config it as MasterController navigation bar display?

[image]

Comment: Try answer present in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484352/navigation-bar-and-status-bar-issue-in-ios-7/24484747#24484747

Comment: @NagaMalleshMaddali I add `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` to PopViewController viewDidLoad method, and no changes in simulator.

Comment: Try adding this in viewDidLoad method : self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

Comment: @NagaMalleshMaddali Not worked as your tips. I then make a IBoutlet for Navigation bar, and add `_navigationBar.translucent = NO;`  in viewDidLoad method, and found Navigation bar background color is not green, is default color.

Comment: How to make Navigation bar height looks as it plus status bar height?

Comment: This is a normal view controller I create, I then drag a NavigationBar  to the controller's view top area in Interface.

Comment: Above suggestions works if you use a UINavigationController. You are seeing problem because you have used a UINavigationBar directly. Try solutions in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901753/ios-7-navigation-bar-toolbar-buttons-very-close-to-status-bar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57517/discussion-between-naga-mallesh-maddali-and-qichunren).

Comment: I drag navigation bar 20px, then use navigation bar delegate, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You have 2 choices.

1. Either create a UINavigationViewController, and set your ViewController has the rootViewController of that UINavigationViewController (it will automatically create a navigation bar with the proper status bar color on top of it),
2. OR you can keep your navigationBar, set its Y origin to be 20, and do the following:

In the .h file:

```
@interface XYZViewController : UIViewController <UIBarPositioningDelegate>
```

And in the .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationBar.delegate = self;
}

- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar { 
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached; 
}
```

EDIT: How to make the bar resize in phone landscape mode:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self.navigationBar sizeToFit];
}
```