# Tabbed application and navigation bar (with title and icons)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In a **tabbed application**, is it possible to have a navigation bar WITHOUT having to use an entire `UINavigationController` as a `UIViewController`? I simply need a navigation bar to position an icon on the right (it should simply open a modal). Of course, I could "fake" it with a `UIView`, but it's not very elegant.

Comment: You can use a NavigationBar with one NavigationItem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with a `UINavigationBar` placed on the top of a view controller.

It is possible to create one from the storyboard, too. Look for the "Navigation Bar" element in the IB Inspector.

[image: Navigation Bar in inspector]

This will behave just like a navigation controler's nav bar, with the exception of the navigation functions.

Comment: I did it, but the strange thing is I can't position it without causing one of the following issues: too much space above that causes to show the background of the main view OR too near to other top elements

Comment: (the UINavigationBehavior is different, the navigation element extents itself till the top border)

Comment: You can easily place a `UIView` there to cover the status bar, or you can refer to this question for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948505/uinavigationbar-status-bar-issue-in-ios7

Comment: For the record, I solved using the solution by matt here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142375/changing-the-height-of-the-navigation-bar-ios-swift