# iOS 7 Status Bar Collides With NavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios7

I have a view controller in my app that has a navigation bar dragged on it in the storyboard. It was working fine in the iOS 6 but in iOS 7 it look like this:

[image: ios 7 status bar nav var]

The status bar and the navigation bar should no collide with each other. I have seen a lot of such questions on the stack overflow but they didn't of much help to me.

Some questions say that i should use this "self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;" but it didn't work. Some say i should remove the navigation bar and embed it inside the navigation controller that i cannot do due to the way my program is implemented. Some solutions suggests to use the view bounds and all but it didn't work for me as well.

What is the one thing that can help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I have embedded the view controller inside a uinavigation controller. Removed the navigation bar that was earlier manually added in it. Now it looks ok in the storyboard but when i run it, it shows the following:

[image: iOS 7 Navigation Status bar]

It is showing text from another view controller that is currently behind it that is its parent view controller. Means its transparent now. Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I have answered on this thread 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294872/ios-7-status-bar-back-to-ios-6-style/19044681#19044681

Comment: Are you not displaying any content below status bar?

Comment: below status bar there is a nav bar and below that there is a text view. But right now the nav bar area is transparent and showing whats behind it another view controller that has presented it.

Comment: I spent a day trying every solution suggested on SO & the apple developer forums - embedding in a navigation controller and living with it's nav bar is the only thing that looks halfway decent. I filed a RADAR and would encourage anyone else that has this problem to do the same.

Comment: 2017, FULL AND DETAILED solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41622164/294884

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The latest version of the iOS has brought many visual changes and from a developer's point of view, the navigation and status bar are two noticeable changes.

The status bar is now transparent and navigation bar behind it shows through. The navigation bar image can even be extended behind the status bar.

First of all, if you are a beginner and have just started iOS development and are confused the way status bar and navigation bar is working, you can simply go through a blog post [HERE](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/) that i found very useful. It has all the information related to navigation and status bar in iOS 7.

Now coming to the answer of your question. First of all i can see two different problems. One is that your status bar and navigation bar are both kind of colliding with each other as shown by you in the question with an image.

**PROBLEM:** Well the problem is that your have earlier dragged a navigation bar in your view controller which was working in iOS 6 correctly but with the arrival of iOS 7 SDK, this approach is resulting in status bar and navigation bar overlapping with each other.

**SOLUTION to First Problem:** You can either use UIBarPositionTopAttached or you can use view bounds and frames, i can also suggest and link you to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/translucent) and bla bla bla but that would take some time for you to solve the issue.

**The best and the most easiest way to solve this issue is to just embed your view controller inside a navigation controller and thats it. You can do it by just selecting the view controller and going to Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller**. (If there is any content on your old navigation bar, you can first drag it down, embed the view controller in navigation controller and then move the bar buttons on the new navigation bar and then delete the old navigation bar)

**SOLUTION to Second Problem:** This solution is for your specific question that you have mentioned in the update and is not for the general public reading this. As you can see that navigation and status bar is not visible and a transparent area is showing the parent view controller. I am not really use why you are facing this issue but most probably because of some third party library like ECSlidingView or any other is involved. You can select this view controller in your storyboard and set the background color of the view to be the same as your navigation bar. This will stop showing the parent view controller behind and your navigation bar and status bar will start showing. Now you can cover the rest of your view controller with text view or what ever your are using in it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: > just embed your view controller inside a navigation controller

this line costs me 2 days of struggling with bar with prompt inside uitabbarcontroller. Now finally the problem is solved, but one question:
now part of the bar is not transparent, transparent part only under status bar. Can you suggest cause?

Comment: found the problem- it was setted background color. it must be transparent.

Comment: If your not using navigation controllers through your whole application (like me), the best thing is to just embed the problem viewcontrollers in navigation controllers. I  salute you for noting that explicitly. I've been fiddling around with this problem for a long time (on and of between development) and finally went through with it and embedded the controllers and it works like a charm! Other solutions just didnt work as expected (probably because im using ECSlidingView as the initial root controller).

Comment: embedding view controller in shell nav controller, clever. +1

Comment: Don't bother with the hacky "shortcut" methods below.  They may or may not work depending on your iOS version and/or view controller.  I tried all of them to see if they would work with a TableView controller and not a single one did.  Just do as KC says.

Answer (score 33):

The navigation bar is too close to the status bar because starting in iOS 7, the status bar is more of an overlay over the whole view controller's view. Since your navigation bar is at (0, 0), the status bar will show on top of the navigation bar. To solve this, simply move the navigation bar down (or, as others have said), create a constraint between the navigation bar and the topLayoutGuide.

When you do that, you will see that there is now a 20 point gap between the navigation bar and the top of the screen. That's because you just moved the navigation bar down 20 points. "But `UINavigationController` can do it right!" Absolutely, and it does so by implementing `UIBarPositioningDelegate` on your view controller. This is a one-method protocol that should be implemented like this:

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar {
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

After adding your view controller as the delegate for the navigation bar, you'll notice the navigation bar is still shifted down 20 points, but its background will extend up underneath the status bar, just like in `UINavigationController`.

Another thing you're seeing is that the navigation bar is translucent, meaning anything underneath the navigation bar will be visible to some extent. The `translucent` property on `UINavigationBar` is set to `YES` by default on iOS 7. Before iOS 7, the default was `NO`.

Comment: A better approach is to make your UINavigationBar's `height` equal to 64 instead of 44.  Then your bar will extend all the way to the top like in Apple's apps.

Comment: @AaronBrager: My solution does the same thing. What makes changing the height to 64 a better solution?

Comment: @Snickers: It does for me and a few others. You're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Perfect! This makes the translucency/blur fade together nicely with the status bar. Thx

Comment: Works as advertised, don't forget to set the class that implements the positionForBar: method as the delegate for the navigation bar. Irritating hack but it works :)

Comment: @zeraien: It's really not a hack. It's designed to be done this way. I think the design could have been a bit better, but this is how it's supposed to be done and probably how `UINavigationController` does it.

Comment: +1 This works perfectly for me. As zeraien said, make sure you set the delegate for the navigation bar.

Comment: The missing step here is set yourself as the navbar delegate. Works great.

Comment: It's amazing how much discussion there is about this topic which bypasses this completely correct and ideal answer. Perfect!

Comment: This answer is still correct if you use a standalone `UINavigationBar` in Xcode 9 / iOS 11

Answer (score 4):

you can simply do this:

1) add a constrain between the **Navigation Bar** and **Top Layout Guide** (select navigationBar, hold ctrl key and go to Bottom Layout Guide, unhold ctrl key)

[image: Add vertical Contrain]

2) select **vertical spacing**:

[image: vertical spacing]

3) set constant to **0**:

[image: vertical spacing constant]

**Result:**

[image: result]

**UPDATE**

In your AppDelegate file you can add this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool 
{
  // Prevent Navigationbar to cover the view
  UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you in your viewDidLoad method you try:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

(by default it is yes now)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/translucent

Answer (score 2):

This works for me i hope you also have same luck :).

Add below code in your view.

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    CGRect tmpFram = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    tmpFram.origin.y += 20;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = tmpFram;
}
```

It basically change location of navigation bar.

Answer (score 2):

First, set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to NO in Info.plist.
Then, in `AppDelegate`'s `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method add:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
   [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
   self.window.clipsToBounds = YES;
   self.window.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height-20);
   self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height);
 }
 return YES;
```

Comment: By far the best solution!

Comment: For 2017, here's the same solution to cut and paste with Swift!  With full details. Hope it helps someone!  http://stackoverflow.com/a/41622164/294884

Answer (score 2):

This is new feature with IOS7. Instead of staring at 20 px navigation bar in IOS7 staring at 0 px. As a solution shift the whole view downwards to 20 px  or you can use image for navigation bar with height 64px.

Answer (score 2):

In case it still helps someone, this is what worked for me for moving the Navigation Bar little bit down in ios 7 and above:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    float iosVersion = 7.0;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= iosVersion) {
        // iOS 7+
        CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
        viewFrame.origin.y += 10;
        self.view.frame = viewFrame;
    }
}
```

On a device with ios 6.1 and below the Navigation Bar will be unchanged, as it was before.

And this is what I used to make the contents of the Status Bar lighter:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Comment: It works for mw as well but don't know this is right approach or not, it might give some trouble in project later on.

Answer (score 2):

If your `UIViewController` is NOT in a `UINavigationController` and you're using `UIStoryBoard`, you can set the "iOS 6/7 Deltas" to 20 for the delta Y, for every subview that needs to be offset from the `UIStatusBar`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> **Using Swift**:

As @Scott Berrevoets said in his answer you need to implement the method `positionForBar` in the protocol `UIBarPositioningDelegate`, but as the `UINavigationBarDelegate` protocol implements this protocol :

```
public protocol UINavigationBarDelegate : UIBarPositioningDelegate {
   ...
}
```

You only need to set the `delegate` of the `UINavigationBar` you set using Storyboard and implement the method and it's done, like in this way:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.navigationBar.delegate = self 
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   func positionForBar(bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
       return UIBarPosition.TopAttached
   }
}
```

**NOTE:**
It's worth to mention if you set the position of the *y-axis* of the navigation bar, let's say to 40 from the top, then it will extend underneath to the top from this position, to simulate the behaviour of the `UINavigationController` you need to set to 20 from the top.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: @AndreyKonstantinov If some solution doesn't solve your problem and for some people do I think it's not a reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7 app occupies 100 % of screen size.This not a problem .
http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/

Answer (score 1):

in earlier iOS window start after statusbar and in iOS 7 window starts from 0px in earlier version view height is 460 (iPhone 4s and earlier) and 548 (iPhone 5) but in iOS 7 view height is 480 (iPhone 4s and earlier) and 568 (iPhone 5 and later) so you have to start view arrangement after 2o px or you have to start view from 20px.

you can write below code in rootviewcontroller or in all viewcontroller for set view from 20px

```
#define IOS7_HEIGHT             64

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    if ([currSysVer compare:@"7.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        CGRect frame=[self.view frame];
        if (frame.origin.y!=IOS7_HEIGHT) {

            frame.origin.y = IOS7_HEIGHT;
            frame.size.height -= IOS7_HEIGHT;
            [self.view setFrame:frame];
            [self.view layoutSubviews];
        }
    }
}
```

here height is 64 because 20 for statusbar and 44 for navigationbar.
try below code it will help you. and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

For the ones who are having problems implementing @Masterfego 's solution (which is also the official, but I have had problems with Xcode 6.3 and automatic constraints), this is what I did:

I have a UIViewController with an added Navigation Bar. I selected the NAvigation bar and added a height constraint of 64px. We later see a warning that the navbar will be higher (but this is what we do). Finally, you can see that the Status bar looks nice and has the same color as the navbar. :)

PS: I can't post images yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create constraints that are attached to the top layout guide to specify the navigation bar's position relative to the status bar. See the [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide: Appearance and Behavior section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1) for more information about using the layout guides.

Comment: the transition guide offers a lot more detail. Can you just update your answer with exactly what i can do to fix this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it's the best answer.
But I wanted know how to use a `Storyboard` and dragged `UINavigationBar` on it.
When I implemented the delegate method, and set the return result to `UIBarPositionTopAttached`, it did not work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    self.navigationbar.delegate = self;
}
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar{
    NSLog(@"Got it");
    //
    //    CGRect frame = self.navigaitonBar.frame;
    //
    //    frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetHeight(frame));
    //    self.navigaitonBar.frame = frame;
    //
    //    NSLog(@"frame %f",frame.origin.y);
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

Comment: Just want use - (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar;  to change the navigation bar position at status bar below.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Xcode 6 and Swift, you can make it:

1. Open to info.plist file of your app.
2. Add a ViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance Boolean key if it is not existing and assign value “NO”.
3. Add “Status bar style” key if it is not existing and select “Opaque black style” value to it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing issue when full screen `ModalViewController` was opening from my `MainViewController`, `NavigationBar` position was getting changed when user was coming back to `MainViewController` from `ModalViewController`.

Issue which I noticed is status bar height was not getting included when user came back to `MainViewController`. Please debug and check origin of your `NavigationBar` before and after coming back to your `ViewController`.

```
// This method will adjust navigation bar and view content.
    private func adjustNavigationControllerIfNeeded() {

        var frame = self.view.frame
        let navigationBarHeight = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height

        if(frame.origin.y == navigationBarHeight && !UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden) { 

   // If status bar height is not included but it is showing then we have to adjust 
      our Navigation controller properly

            print("Adjusting navigation controller")
            let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

            frame.origin.y += statusBarHeight // Start view below navigation bar
            frame.size.height -= statusBarHeight
            self.view.frame = frame

            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.origin.y = statusBarHeight // Move navigation bar
        }
    }
```

And call it from viewWillAppear method -

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.adjustNavigationControllerIfNeeded()
}
```