# app Title merges with iphone meta data in iOS 7.x

Tags: ios

I am testing my app on device with iOS7
My application title seems to merge with the other meta data that apple provides such as Time , Battery life , service provider signal / wifi

This would be very annoying for the end user and would be bad user experience

However the same thing seems cleanly separated in iOS6.x on device

Here are screen prints ( using simulator - which is mimicing what is happening on device )
with iOS6
[image: this is with iOS6]

This is with iOS7
[image]

Can anyone please suggest what would need to be done to ensure my app title does not merge with the device meta data for iOS7 ?

Thanks
akila

Comment: check this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105766/ios-7-status-bar-collides-with-navigationbar

Comment: @ashish +1 for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

You have write this code in your code file:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
        return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

And set status bar style setting in info.plist file like shown in screenshot.

[image]