# Custom Navigation Bar image - iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

In iOS 7 , I have used custom navigation bar here .

But the problem is How can I set the image as it is 320*64 but the navigation item iOS is allowing me is 44pixel .. I am able to add the image on navigation controller successfully but don't have any idea about this .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because Navigation bar is 44 pixel in height and status bar is 20 pixel in height. In IOS7 the status bar is now transparent, that means the navigation bar behind it shows through. In some cases, the background image for a navigation bar can extend up behind the status bar.

if you hide status bar in your application you will find that the navigation bar will be smaller in height. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105766/ios-7-status-bar-collides-with-navigationbar) has some nice discussion about this topic.

Comment: Special thanks for that link .. it solved my problem :)