# UIViewController setTitle: causes NavigationBar To overlap Status Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

[image]Any time I try to set the title for a `UIViewController` subclass the `navigationBar` suddenly overlaps the StatusBar and looks wrong. Not sure what might be causing this.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
      [super viewDidLoad];
      [self setTitle: @"Player Profile"];
}
```

This is part of an `RESideMenuController` so not sure if this would be a problem?

Comment: maybe you should call [super viewDidLoad] first

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 Status Bar Collides With NavigationBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105766/ios-7-status-bar-collides-with-navigationbar)

Comment: refer these link i hope it helps.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105766/ios-7-status-bar-collides-with-navigationbar?lq=1