# iOS status bar - View Controller to Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have done a little research and understand that a quick fix for iOS 7+ suffering from the overlying status bar issue (introduced in iOS 7 with the new status bar layout) on a view controller is to put it in a Navigation Controller.

However, when I go to Xcode the option is greyed out. What am I doing wrong? (I am an Xcode beginner, so bear with me).

Is using a Navigation Controller the correct way to do it?

[image: Xcode screenshot]

As you can see here, the Navigation Controller is behind the status bar, not extended below it:

[image: iOS screenshot]

Comment: You can only embed navigation controller in a **UIViewController** class . In your screenshot you trying to embed tis in UIview it is not possible

Comment: Ah - makes sense. What is the best way to fix the issue in question - which is correctly adapting the navigation bar so it isn't lapped behind the status bar?

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105766/ios-7-status-bar-collides-with-navigationbar

Answer (score 0):

Its looking like that your controller is already in a Navigation controller stack, thats why it is not showing the option to embed in Navigation controller. Check your storyboard.

Comment: Hi Shiv, the project is a type which doesn't use a story board (this is a "plugin" for a framework). If it is, on iOS 7+ the navbar is showing behind the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

You Create Xib its set the Top Bar or Navigation Bar, **select the XIB** then see the right side select **Attributes Inspector** then set the **status bar, Top Bar** etc, then see my screenshot below,

[image]
create `UIBarbutton` programmatically code is below,

`viewDidLoad` Method:

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backAction)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBarButtonItem animated:NO];
```

its working for me, hope its helpful

Comment: I have update my answer, set the status bar is Inferred, then create the `UIBarButton` programmatically, its working for me

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a go