# Staus Bar on launching app ios 6 and 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

**In my app i use ios 6 as deployment targer.**

i set View controller-based status bar appearance  to No in .Plist. status bar,s back ground color change to green as i want on ios 7. but when i run my app on ios 6 it remain black  only when launch image is displayed rest is fine to whole app.

i use this code also in my app delegate...

```
if (!SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

How to change back ground of status bar background color and text color while launching the app on both ios 6 and ios 7.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19063734/2515572)

Comment: thanks. the problem is when app displaying the launch screen in ios 6 status bar is still black.status bar is display as i want . problem obly in ios 6 when app launching.

Comment: hide status bar in both versions

Answer (score 0):

1) set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to YES in the plist

2) in viewDidLoad do a `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];`

3) add the following method:

```
 -(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{ 
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
 }
```

Comment: i try it but in ios 6 the status bar is displaying black although it display green in ios 7 . my launch image has green color.

Answer (score 0):

Because your navigation bar is translucent = YES which is default for iOS 7. Maybe, you also set translucent = YES for iOS 6. Set it to NO for iOS 6 so that it also works on app launch.

Answer (score 0):

In appdelegate.m put.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    return YES;
}
```