# change the background of the statusbar with rubymotion

Tags: ios7, statusbar, rubymotion

I try to change the background of the statusBar like this
[image]

but any attempt fails and I do not know if I use well good method.

the constraint is that the navigationBar should be hidden and I can not do otherwise, and I do not know if it's because of ca that I can not change the background of the statusBar.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21044718/204044) and adapt it for RubyMotion.

```rb
if UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion.to_f >= 7.0
  view = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame([[0, 0], [320, 20]])
  view.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithRed(0/255.0, green:0/255.0, blue:0/255.0, alpha:1.0)
  self.window.rootViewController.view.addSubview(view)
end
```

Comment: You can replace self.window.rootViewController.view.addSubview(view) with self.view.addSubview(view) if you call this in a ViewController; in this case you can customize the background per VC