# changing the background color of status bar in ios7

Tags: ios7

How to change the background color of status bar in ios7 while having different color of navigation bar? 
I know in ios7 status bar color take color value from navigation bar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the status bar background color and text color on iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063365/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-7)

Answer (score 0):

Change the tint colour and barTint colour of navigation bar changes colour of status bar for predefined values  if you want custom Colours add subview to navigation bar in viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200.0f/255.0f green:126/255.0f blue:200.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Answer (score 0):

add subview to navigation bar with desired color as background colour like this:

```
UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 20)];

view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:view];
```

It works for me to change colour of status bar.