# iOS8 change status bar color without using UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, colors, uinavigationbar, tint

I'd like to change the status bar color without having to show the UINavigationBar.

```
setBarTintColor works fine if 
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

however I'm using a custom control that means I have to set

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

which then means the status bar color is white.

How can I change the status bar color without showing the UINavigationBar?

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your question well 
Here is how to change the `UIStatusBarStyle` on each `UIViewController`

so u will need to add those lines in your `app-info.plist`

1-

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

and inside your viewController `-(void)viewDidLoad;`
call the following

2-

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

then declare this selector

3-

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

4- here is the list of `UIStatusBarStyle`

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIStatusBarStyle) {
    UIStatusBarStyleDefault                                     = 0, // Dark content, for use on light backgrounds
    UIStatusBarStyleLightContent     NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) = 1, // Light content, for use on dark backgrounds

    UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use UIStatusBarStyleLightContent") = 1,
    UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque      NS_ENUM_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use UIStatusBarStyleLightContent") = 2,
};
```

if u was talking about changing the status bar background color i think u have to see the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21044718/1447546

Comment: so how to specify the color it self