# Status Bar in Oracle MAF

Tags: ios, oracle, oracle-maf

Is it possible to change the status bar (coming above the header facet) color/ or make the screen full screen for Oracle MAF applications ?
[image]

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063365/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-7) should help you

Comment: But i am working in Oracle MAF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be useful for those who have requirement like above

Add `<fullscreenLayout>fullscreen</fullscreenLayout>` to `maf.config.xml`
then In Lifecyclelistner `start()` method add `AdfmfContainerUtilities.setStatusBarStyle(AdfmfContainerUtilities.STATUS_BAR_STYLE.LIGHT);`

Comment: So where is your color? I thought that was your problem, not hiding the status bar. :) this STATUS_BAR_STYLE.LIGHT is not a color selection.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was registered as a new enhancement in 2014. I am not sure if it ready yet. Here is [the link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3639333?start=0&tstart=0).

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, @AnandRaj, I am glad to be helpful, if you need anything else, please tell me.