# Is there a way to set custom color for status bar text and background?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I know how to change text color to black or white, but is there some way to change text to green and BG to red for example?

Comment: NO, there is no option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of the status bar may only be black or white. You can read more in Apple's [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html).

The background color is based on what is behind the status bar. You could, for example, add a 20-pixel tall view with a solid color at the top of your view to color it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21044718/137744) is a description of how to do that programmatically in Objective-C. You can use the same idea using Storyboard.