# Is it possible to change the status bar text color?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a dark theme for my app, where all the background is black and text and controls are orange. I also want the status bar to correspond to this theme, but `.lightContent` option, which is designed for dark backgrounds, returns white text color. I was wondering if it's at all possible to make status bar text something other than black or white (orange, in my case)?

[image]

Comment: There is no API that allows this in the iOS SDK.

Comment: I found  a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063365/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-7, but it comes with a warning that this can cause app rejection. So I guess there really is no legal way)

Comment: No you can't ... If anyhow you changed your app may reject

Comment: @DenysTriasunov that is about the background not the text color.

Comment: http://jitu1990.blogspot.in/2017/06/background-color-of-status-bar.html

Comment: @JitendraSolanki it not about the background of the status bar, bit the text on the statusbar. You link is about changing the background.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the status bar's text color as the apple provided only two colors for displaying status bar text which is white and black.

To display white text add the following stuff to your project Info.plist

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = false

Status bar style = Transparent black style (alpha of 0.5)
```

To display black text add the following stuff to your project Info.plist

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = false

Status bar style = Gray style (default) OR Opaque black style
```