# Android and iPhone topbar/Statusbar changing Pragmatically

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, statusbar

I am new to App development I am trying to make an app which needs to access and change top bar/status bar on both iOS and Android. I have Searched many Sites even StackOverflow but all I get was It shows how to change colour of text in these bars, there are tremendous Coders are out there working fantastic on both platform, please can any one give me is it could be done? if yes then what is the approach. For more clarification I am uploading Images for top bars.

**Android**

[image]

And **Iphone**
[image]

> This is what I want to do. Change items or add items in the statusbar

[image]

Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the status bar background color and text color on iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063365/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-7)

Comment: if you have clearly read the question I have mentioned I don't need only color changing. I need full access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS:

- Change in info.plist the row View controller-based status bar
  appearance and set it to NO
- Change in appDelegate.swift in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

  UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

Comment: thanks for considering but I want to completely access to add up some things like strings etc. is that would be possible. ?

Comment: @Ahsan can u explain what u are trying to achieve? with an e.g. with respect to screenshot above.

Comment: Added now please check.

Comment: I don't think you can do that in iOS . Apple has specifically written in their human interface guidelines "Use the system-provided status bar. People expect the status bar to be consistent systemwide. Don’t replace it with a custom status bar." for reference :https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/bars/status-bars/

Comment: I think you can either completely hide your status bar or u can  add a UIView on top of the staus bar of size (320 x 20) but whether it will be accepted in App Store or not.... I have no guarantee

Comment: okay Thankyou, but I need that UIView to pe placed on there if the app is in background state . would that be possible .

Comment: nope... it can only work on particular functionalities such as gps, voice and all