# Screen background color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to set the screen's background color to pink however, when I use `edgesIgnoringSageArea(.all)` it is being ignored and remains white.

Is this perhaps an **Xcode 11 Beta 2** bug?

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var sliderValue: Float = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()

            HStack {
                Image("lectric")
                Text("Some Text").font(.largeTitle)
            }

            Slider(value: $sliderValue, from: 1, through: 100, by: 1)

            Spacer()
        }.padding(.horizontal, 50)
         .background(Color.pink)
         .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hard to say. First, why aren't you already using beta 3? It's been available for 3 days and may answer your question. Second, have you tried using a `ZStack` to set background color? Maybe it's not the thing you want to do, but considering we're barely in beta 3... does it work?

Comment: Using Beta 3 and applying `ZStack` solves it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. maybe your code will work in a future beta - make sure to check it out each week. Isn't it fun working with bleeding edge software? :-)

Answer (score 1):

This code will change the navigation background color

```
 init(){
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The **automatic preview** can't handle `SafeArea` yet.
If you **run** the application it will work as intended.

Answer (score -2):

Thats the status bar. It is not handled by safe area. You have to change the window color or add an subview to change status bar color.

Here some ideas for status bar [How to change Status Bar text color in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios)

and here are some ideas with custom views

[How to change the status bar background color and text color on iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063365/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-7)

Comment: The question is about SwiftUI. Both of your links are for UIKit.

Answer (score -2):

So, it seems that you want to present same color in entire screen, the status bar component always stays separate from rest of the view so i would recommend try changing the status bar color specifically. Please try the below snippet method.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   self.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: .blue)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


func setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {

    guard let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView else { return }

    statusBar.backgroundColor = color
}
}
```

You can obviously make this method generic also and call from appdelegate or some common class.