# How to change the color of navigationBar along with the status Bar in iOS?

Tags: ios, navbar

I have a view Controller. I have added a navigationBar from Object library and I have change its BackgroundColor. Now, the problem is that my statusBar color is dull White and its looking bad. How do I change that color?

[What I an Getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRJyW.png)

[What I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSL6Z.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the status bar background color and text color on iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063365/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the background color to the view controller's view. or add UIView at the most top of the screen behind the navigation bar and set it's background color then set navigation background color to clear