# Modal View Controller Slides Underneath Status Bar in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, autolayout

When I use a modal view controller in iOS7 it slides underneath the status bar.  Is there a way to stop that from happening without having to adjust the view based on what os it's running on? You can see that the Close button is pushed up underneath the Carrier text on the status bar.  Is there any way to get the modal view controller to recognize my status bar?

[image: The Close button is pressed up to close to the carrier label]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737186/position-of-navigation-bar-for-modal-view-ios7 which has a great answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this? [UINavigationBar/Status Bar issue in IOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948505/uinavigationbar-status-bar-issue-in-ios7)

There are a couple of things you can try, but I think what you're looking for is here, in the iOS7 Transition Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with a modal view.  Only with navigation controller views, which I already have working.

Comment: Nevermind.  I was locking the navigation bar to the view instead of the TopLayoutGuide.  Exactly what I was looking for.  One thing I noticed though, sometimes the top layout guide constraint would lock to the bottom of the navigation bar, which would cause it to be off.  Need to create a new top constraint to the top layout guide and delete the bottom constraint in this case.

Comment: iOS 7 Transition Guide link broken; please transcribe any useful sections before the information is gone forever. For now, can be located at [this third-party website](http://blog.thiebault.be/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/IOS7-TransitionGuide.pdf).