# Matching navigation bar and status bar colour

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I've just added a navigation bar to my Swift tabbed application. I have moved it down by 20 so that it lines up with the status bar however there is now obviously a gap at the top. Apps in iOS seem to match the navigation bar to the status bar colour so I was wondering if anyone could let me know how I get my app to match the nav bar colour and the status bar colour?

Thanks

Comment: How are you able to make it taller? I can only find an option for increasing the width.

Comment: I set the height using an auto layout constraint (the status bar doesn't appear in landscape mode on iPhone so I set the height to 64 for the "Any Width, Regular Height" size class)

Comment: Try this, if you don't want to embed a navigation controller : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737186/position-of-navigation-bar-for-modal-view-ios7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be adding a navigation bar manually to your view. It is far easier and ideal to use a `UINavigationController` instead. Instead of putting a view controller directly as one of the tabs, wrap it in a `UINavigationController` and put that as the tab's view controller. Then the positioning and sizing will be handled for you and you will be better setup for future releases of iOS.

```
var myController = MyController()
var navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myController)
// use navController wherever you were using myController before
```

Comment: This is my first application so I am not confident in all of the terminology. Could you explain the steps I would take to achieve what you are suggesting? What I currently have is a tab view controller with a first view controller and a second view controller connected to it.

Comment: @user3746428 Are you setting up your tab controller in a Storyboard or in code?

Comment: I'm using storyboard.

Comment: @user3746428 so instead of connecting your tab view controller directly to you view controller, put a UINavigationController in-between. UINavigationController is one of the objects you can drag onto the storyboard.

Comment: Ah! I've just started learning Swift and Xcode so I still have a lot to learn but that works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help. Yup, learning is just about solving one problem at a time :)