# Transforming app from iOS6 to iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

[image][image]i want to change `iOS6` application to `iOS7`.(i.e)i want iOS7 compatibility. I am using customised navigation bar and native tabbar in my application. When i run my application in iOS7 simulator,view is moving up. I have set the `DELTA Y` value to 20. After that also i unable to get the `uiview`  and `uiobjects` in correct position.

Can someone help me?.

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/ContentViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH10-SW1

Comment: and the start of the doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Status bar and navigation bar issue in IOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980925/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-issue-in-ios7)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set Delta Y to -20 not 20! Also regarding the UIControls check autolayout constraints. If you set all this app properly, your app will play nice in both iOS 6 and 7.

Comment: If i set Delta Y to -20, then View is moving up. that is, status bar is overlaping the view. view moves behind the status bar.

Comment: set in your `vieDidLoad` method `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;`

Comment: Sorry then also me not getting it. I am using customised navigation controller.

Comment: post screenshots of the UI in ios 6 and 7 if possible.

Comment: I have tried.but i dont have enough npoints to post the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting  self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone for iOS 7.  If this doesn't work ,additionally set delta to 64 pixels as it seems you are using UINavigationController and for that you have to set it to 20+44 .

Comment: if i set delta to 64,my view is moving down.i want to know,whether i have to set delta as +20 or -20.some friends said me to set it to -20.but i set the value to +20 and i got my view in correct position. but not the UIcontrols used in view.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729064/ios7-status-bar-over-navigation-bar?rq=1)